# Add video player and execute it after ajax response on Angular

Tags: angularjs, html, html5-video

I'm uploading a file (video) to a server and need to play it after processing it (there's a webservice to query the processing status).

How can I add a video player (maybe the HTML5 video tag) to a DIV only after the response of this webservice?

Current code to load the video causes unnecessary server request to a non existing url.

Angular filter to allow the url

```
app.filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<video src="{{encodedFileUrl | trustUrl}}" controls></video>
```

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: Actually this is what I'm looking for. Some code sample on adding HTML elements to a container. My code currently has a tag `<video  src="{{encodedFileUrl | trustUrl}}" controls></video>`, which does a useless request at page load.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Videogular](http://www.videogular.com/), angular based video player